# In XPages I can't get the File Upload Control to work inside of Mobile Controls

Tags: xpages

Now that iOS devices can upload from their picture library or camera, I'm trying to use the file upload control to get ahold of these pictures via an xpage.  If it's a plain XPage it's working fine - but if I try to wrap this inside of the Mobile Controls from the extension library I can't get the picture to save.  Other values save to the document but not the picture.
The file upload control is bound to a rich text field.

Any ideas would be appreciated!!!!

Comment: David - I haven't peeked in to the mobile control, but does it do a partial or full refresh when saving? The file upload requires a full refresh.

Comment: I've tried full.  I think it's something Mobile controls is doing.  Need to try and iframe I think based on a toohey article - similar problem with using file upload inside a dialogbox.  what a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Place the file upload inside an Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Are you saying that you can make the file upload control work with an XPage on an iOS device? I was of the clear impression that you do not have access to the camera from a web-app. In this case you need to wrap your web-app into a layer that can access the physical (e.g. Apache Cordova aka PhoneGap)....?

I know that some of these features are on their way in html5, however, the have so far been very unreliable (crashing the phones often).

/John